# how to save QJsonDocument to file

Tags: c++, qt

I started learning Qt and i have a problem, basically i'm trying to make this simple app -3 line edits and one button that will get your name etc from line edits and put it into JSON file. Right now i'm able to get the data and put it into Qjson object and then put the object into Qjson document but i can't save the json document with a QFile.

I've tried to look it up but haven't found anything that works

```
   void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
   {
       qDebug()<<"ok button clicked";

       QString firstName=ui->NameEdit->text();
       QString lastName=ui->LnameEdit->text();
       QString age=ui->ageEdit->text();


       QJsonObject user;
       user["firstname"]=firstName;
       user["lastname"]=lastName;
       user["age"]=age;
       qDebug()<<user;

       QJsonDocument userDoc(user);
       qDebug()<<userDoc;


       QFile users("users.json");
       users.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
       //it is working to this point
       users.write(userDoc.toJson());
       users.close();
       //when i open "users.json" file it's always empty
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the `open()` returns `true` and `write()` doesn't return -1?

Comment: i have checked that and file opens correctly and write doesn't return -1

Comment: What is the problem manifestation? You can't find a file? Try use absolute path. File can be found, but it is empty? Or file doesn't contains what it supposed to contain?

Comment: file opens correctly as it is but nothing is beeing written to it

Comment: Which platform is this running on? Windows? Linux?

Comment: im running Manjaro

Comment: Have you tried calling `open()` with `QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text`?

Comment: i've tried but it doesn't make any difference, qDebug()<<users.readAll() gives me " "

Comment: ok i somehow menaged to make it work thanks for all  the help guys ;D

Comment: Check the return value of open(), and errorString() if it returns false. (and readAll() will do nothing on a file opened WriteOnly)